# Set dropdown select by value

Tags: google-apps-script, dropdown

Is it possible to set selected specific item of dropdown in Google apps script (Gmail add-on) from the action?

Example: I have one dropdown with 5 items (10, 20, 30, 40, 50) and one button. Default selected item of dropdown is 10 (`dropdown.AddItem(10, 10, true)`). When I click button I want to change selected item of dropdown to 40. Is it possible to do?

**UPDATED:**

```
function onHomepage(e) {
  var max = CardService.newSelectionInput()
      .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
      .setTitle('Max')
      .setFieldName('max_field')
      .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('maxHandler'));  

  for (let i = 10; i <= 100; i += 10) {
    var selected = false;
    if (i === 10)
      selected = true;
    max.addItem(i + "$", i, selected);
  }

  var _btn = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Button')
      .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
      .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('btnClicked'));

  var btn = CardService.newButtonSet()
      .addButton(_btn);  

  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(max)
    .addWidget(btn);

  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setName('cardName')
    .addSection(section)
    .build();
}

function btnClicked(e) {
  var selectedMax = e.formInput.max_field;
  console.log(selectedMax);

  // TODO: set selected dropdown for 40$ item
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think if I understand correctly you have to trigger a rebuild of the card... but without any code or context it's a little hard to say for sure. Can you provide more context?

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou, updated my question and added example code in pastebin https://pastebin.com/LUXKyPGC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need re-render the card on button click:

```
function onHomepage(e) {
  return createCard(10)
}

function btnClicked(e) {
  var selectedMax = e.formInput.max_field;

  return createCard(40)
}

function createCard(value) {
  var max = CardService.newSelectionInput()
      .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
      .setTitle('Max')
      .setFieldName('max_field')
      .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('maxHandler')); 


  for (let i = 10; i <= 100; i += 10) {
    var selected = false;
    if (i === value)
      selected = true;
    max.addItem(i + "$", i, selected);
  }

  var _btn = CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Button')
      .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
      .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('btnClicked'));

  var btn = CardService.newButtonSet()
      .addButton(_btn); 

  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
    .addWidget(max)
    .addWidget(btn);

  return CardService.newCardBuilder()
    .setName('cardName')
    .addSection(section)
    .build();
}
```

Just separate out your card creation code from `onHomepage()` into a different function (for example `createCard()` and call it from both `onHomepage()` and from `btnClicked()`.

Comment: thank you. Is it ok to re-create card multiple times?

Comment: Absolutely - creating a new card and returning it with new information is how updating a card is performed :)